# java.io.NotSerializableException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using Struts2 on Google App Engine. on my local development box , the app is working fine.But on 
uploading to google's cloud ,I get the below exception

I am using following binaries

struts2.3.1.2 (& dependent jar files)
xwork-core-2.3.1.2
GAE SDK Release: 1.6.6

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager.serialize(SessionManager.java:373)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.DatastoreSessionStore.createEntityForSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:71)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.DatastoreSessionStore.saveSession(DatastoreSessionStore.java:93)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SessionManager$AppEngineSession.save(SessionManager.java:164)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:41)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:477)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I have even tried with latest version of xwork-core API but no gain.
I have seen this kind of problem reported on this site,but there is no satisfactory solution or answer to the question.
can someone help me in resolving this..?

If the use of ArrayList in the Action class is the root class of this ,as a workaround should I go for alternative of ArrayList ?which one is suggested ..?

-thanks
Ma